# androidx.annotation.ContentView not found in release build

Tags: android, android-proguard

I'm trying to test my app in release mode, I have this in my proguard config:

```
-keep class androidx.annotation.**
```

yet the app somehow always crashes with:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/annotation/ContentView;
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:123)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:275)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was going insane trying to figure out why I also got that error all of the sudden. After digging into my module's `build.gradle` I noticed this, tbh I don't even remember the reason why I had to force these resolution strategies.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force deps.kotlin.stdlib
        force deps.androidx.annotation <-- REMOVE THIS LINE
    }
}
```

Removing `force deps.androidx.annotation` fixed the issue!

For reference, these are the values

```
kotlin.stdlib = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$versions.kotlin"
androidx.annotation = "androidx.annotation:annotation:$versions.annotation"
```

This is some kind of bug incompatibility with **androidx**.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`ContenView` was just recently added to *androidx.annotation:annotation* library.
and will be part of *1.1.x* release

So the solution is to use the latest annotation library, which is in the time of writing *1.1.0-rc1*

```
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0-rc01'
```

See related commit for details.
[Android Open Source Project - Add a @ContentView annotation to ComponentActivity, Fragment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/37f2d45370dc3d53ea3f327068edd21698c2e959)